# c++ timer linux

Tags: c++, linux, time, timer

I need to know how create a timer or measure out 500ms in C++ in a linux environment. I have tried using gettimeofday and using the time structure but cant get the correct precision for milliseconds. What I am trying to do is have an operation continue for a max of 500ms...after 500ms something else happens.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to retrieve the current processor time in Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107121/how-to-retrieve-the-current-processor-time-in-linux)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have access to C++11 then your best bet it to use std::chrono library

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration

I aren't entirely sure what you want to do with it do you want to wait for exactly 500ms?

you can so this for that

```
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
```

you can do an operation until 500 milliseconds has elapsed by getting a time pointer and check to see whether timepoint - system_time::now() is greater than 500ms

```
//if you compiler supports it you can use auto
std::chrono::system_clock::time_point start=std::chrono::system_clock::now();

while(start-std::chrono::system_clock::now() 
          < std::chrono::milliseconds(500))
{
    //do action
}
```

If you don't have C++11 this will also work with boost chrono library. The advantage of this approach is that it is portable unlike using linux time functions.

Comment: 1. c++0x is still in experimental stage. 2. CPU is tied up during the waiting period.

Comment: 1). on GCC at least std::chrono is working excellently, 2). if you mean on the sleep function then it will be idle, if you mean on the later example then it does exactly what the OP wants to do an action until 500ms has elapsed. I don't get get what you mean by the waiting period.

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't really clear about why you "can't get the correct precision" or what happens when you try to do that, but if you're having trouble with `gettimeofday`, consider using `clock_gettime` instead. `man clock_gettime` for details.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are in Linux, you can use the system call usleep

```
   int usleep(useconds_t usec);
```

Which will let your process sleep for some microseconds period.

Comment: Or `nanosleep`  or perhaps even some multiplexing call like `poll` (e.g. if you also wait for some input)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <atomic>

void keep_busy(std::chrono::milliseconds this_long,std::atomic<bool> *canceled) {
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    while(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() < start+this_long) {
        std::cout << "work\n";
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(50));
        if(canceled->load()) {
            std::cout << "canceling op\n";
            throw "operation canceled";
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    std::atomic<bool> canceled(false);
    auto future = std::async(std::launch::async,
        keep_busy,std::chrono::milliseconds(600),&canceled);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
    canceled.store(true);
    try {
        future.get();
        std::cout << "operation succeded\n";
    } catch( char const *e) {
        std::cout << "operation failed due to: " << e << '\n';
    }
}
```

I'm not entirely sure this is correct...